# Internet Explorer trying to run csc.exe

Tags: internet-explorer

Every so often I get the following dialog:

> A website wants to open web content using this program on your
>   computer.

The program it wants to run is csc.exe (C# compiler)

If I say "Don't bother again" and click "Disallow" the message keeps showing after a while.

What is invoking it? How do I stop it?

[image]

Comment: That IE window has *four* different search bars on it! Really?

Comment: The computer is not mine, i also get amased about the amount of useless toolbars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet dollars to donuts that call to CSC is not not directly from the site. This is also most definitely **not** a WPF nor Silverlight application.

The site is an agency of the United States government -- NOAA, specifically. I just opened it in IE. No popups, no issues -- essentially no reproduction of the issue. And no plugins loaded; all imagery was web-standard graphic files.

This indicates that something else is happening. Now, normally I'd blame a toolbar or other Browser Helper Object (BHO). However, at least in terms of the *visible* toolbars, two are known quantities (Yahoo and Google). I'm not familiar with the middle one (the "Identity Defender"), so I can't judge it either way without more research.

There are probably, however, other BHOs installed, or some other malware, which intercepts web addresses and occasionally redirects or quietly launches requests to other sites. Try going to this site on the end user's computer, and watch the status bar *very* carefully -- you're looking for addresses that wouldn't make sense being requested from a US Government web page.

If you see any suspicious URL requests, bingo, we're in a world where -- at least some -- web requests are being spawned without the user requesting them. Now that we know that, your job just became malware removal and DNS troubleshooting.

For most end users, this is the point where I wag my finger disapprovingly, turn on their UAC, and tell them that if they turn it off again I will refuse to support them. Tough love, I know. But I only support friends and family -- and I do that for free -- so I don't want to have my time wasted constantly.

After you get through with any necessary chastising, you will need to get some good, reliable malware removal tools and go to work. At the point where you identify the specific malware, you might consider asking a separate question here on SuperUser regarding removal of the specific issues.

Comment: What?  You think a guy with four search toolbars showing might have some sort of malware?

Does UAC really work for people?  Seems like it would work for people with a clue that some software wants to do bad things to their computer, but there's a large class of people who want to just click "allow" to everything and get on with their lives.

+1 for a nice answer, btw.

Comment: UAC actually works, this particular user hits calls me constantly about UAC nagging screen to see if it's OK to allow. Two of the toolbars is fault of some other IT careless guy who didn't disabled the option when installing google desktop and yahoo messenger, BTW i don't know how did he get the other one.

Comment: @Chris Farmer: To be fair, a couple of those toolbars are known-safe, but I cede your point. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm just being a little over the top. Yahoo and google bars are probably not too problematic. The MyIdentityDefender is a little more suspect!

Comment: I felt the same way, but didn't do sufficient research on it to make a judgment call. A cursory glance on Google didn't turn up any red flags -- but we're talking about a 5-second search-and-scan, no real digging. At this stage, to fully troubleshoot, I'd have to sit at the user's machine. And I don't clean up spyware. At least, not for free!